# CSS Float Degradation Right to Bottom

Tags: html, css, css-float, graceful-degradation

I am trying to float an element on my page as a right sidebar, but to enable degradation to put the element below the content and above the footer for smaller screen sizes. Here is what I have so far: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVb69/2/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.footer{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}

.sidebar{
    //float:bottom;
}

@media (min-width : 400px){
    .sidebar {
        //float:right;
        //width:20%
    }

    .grid {
        float:left;
        width:80%
    }

    .element {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
        width:33%;
    }
}@media (min-width : 500px){
    .sidebar {
        float:right;
        width:20%
    }

    .grid {
        float:left;
        width:80%
    }

    .element {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
        width:33%;
    }
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class='sidebar'>
        <p>SIDEBAR: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec arcu sed ipsum placerat ornare id ut augue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi laoreet tellus purus, vitae feugiat elit accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque magna metus, pharetra ut mollis vel, dictum in purus. Mauris bibendum euismod lorem, luctus gravida turpis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='grid'>
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid'>
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 6</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 7</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 7</p>
            </div>
            <div class='element'>
                <p>Box 9</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        <p>FOOTER: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is that when the screen is less than 500px the sidebar goes to the top **instead of the bottom**. I can't seem to figure out how to make it "float" to the bottom. underneath the content I tried `float:bottom` but obviously that did not work. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You can not do that with “regular” CSS alone (not unless you want to use flexbox), as long as the sidebar is the first element in your code/DOM. You would have to change the order of `#sidebar` and `#content` for that to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the order of your sidebar and content (the content is more important to begin with). [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angstrey/uVb69/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class='content'>
    <div class='grid'>
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid'>
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 6</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 7</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 7</p>
        </div>
        <div class='element'>
            <p>Box 9</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='sidebar'>
    <p>SIDEBAR: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec arcu sed ipsum placerat ornare id ut augue. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi laoreet tellus purus, vitae feugiat elit accumsan tincidunt. Pellentesque magna metus, pharetra ut mollis vel, dictum in purus. Mauris bibendum euismod lorem, luctus gravida turpis.</p>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
    <p>FOOTER: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}

.sidebar{
    float: right;
}

.content {
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width : 400px){
    .sidebar {
        //float:right;
        //width:20%
    }

    .grid {
        float:left;
        width:80%
    }

    .element {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
        width:33%;
    }
}

@media (min-width : 500px){
    .sidebar {
        float:right;
        width:20%
    }

    .grid {
        float:left;
        width:80%
    }

    .element {
        float:left;
        height:50px;
        width:33%;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, you are a genious and a scholar. It is the simple stuff in life that I forget. I tried very similiar but I forgot to do the float left on the content duh!